# Best Way to Clean CV Joints of Old Grease

Tags: cleaning, axle, cv-joint

I'll be replacing the CV boots on my axles pretty soon and was wondering what the best way to clean the old grease off is.  Are there any common solvents that would be useful, or are just a bunch of old throw away rags all I need?  I'd like to do it as cleanly and quickly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean off the bulk of the grease with rags, then dump them in a bucket of solvent (gas, kerosene, parts cleaner, mineral spirits). Seafoam or brake cleaner also work, but they're more expensive. Let them sit for a bit, then pull them out, wipe them clean with another rag, re-grease and reassemble.

Comment: After cleaning as described here, I usually use my air compressor to blow any remaining solvent away.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing: Brake cleaner is best, because it leaves no residue, but it always seems to take so much. Good point about using it for the final clean-up.